# How do I stop my node app after using forever to start it

Tags: next.js, forever

I'm running my nextjs app with forever like this:

forever start -c "npm start" ./

that works great for starting it, but I have found no way of stopping it. If I kill the process, the app just starts back up with a new process. How do I do a stop?

I'm running my nextjs app on a Linode server running Ubuntu.

Comment: I have same issue. I kill process manually by kill <process id>

Answer (score 1):

1. use forever list and you could see uid in terminal
2. forever stop **your-app-uid**
3. if you would like to stop all, please run forever stopall